# generate an id, which fulfills a cycle sequence of another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame:
*) id: activity identifier
*) cycle: shows the activity of each cycle, following the following sequence 1,2,3,4,5,6 (Starts at 1 and ends at 6)
*) team: team name

**GET THE NEW ID**
id_nuevo: id that mentions the cycle, in case the sequence is not fulfilled

| id | ciclo | equipo | id_nuevo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1428171 | 3 | Eq01 | null |
| 1427533 | 4 | Eq01 | null |
| 1427950 | 5 | Eq01 | null |
| 1427956 | 6 | Eq01 | null |
| 1427957 | 1 | Eq01 | 1 |
| 1427960 | 2 | Eq01 | 1 |
| 1427913 | 3 | Eq01 | 1 |
| 1430050 | 4 | Eq01 | 1 |
| 1431974 | 5 | Eq01 | 1 |
| 1431534 | 6 | Eq01 | 1 |
| 1428030 | 1 | Eq01 | null |
| 1428031 | 2 | Eq01 | null |
| 1427930 | 3 | Eq01 | null |
| 1427601 | 1 | Eq01 | 2 |
| 1427578 | 2 | Eq01 | 2 |
| 1427927 | 3 | Eq01 | 2 |
| 1427532 | 4 | Eq01 | 2 |
| 1427977 | 5 | Eq01 | 2 |
| 1427980 | 6 | Eq01 | 2 |
| 1433246 | 3 | Eq01 | null |
| 1433251 | 4 | Eq01 | null |
| 1427585 | 1 | Eq01 | 3 |
| 1427974 | 2 | Eq01 | 3 |
| 1427910 | 3 | Eq01 | 3 |
| 1430905 | 4 | Eq01 | 3 |
| 1431681 | 5 | Eq01 | 3 |
| 1432176 | 6 | Eq01 | 3 |
| 1433005 | 1 | Eq01 | null |
| 1434616 | 2 | Eq01 | null |
| 1433245 | 4 | Eq01 | null |

So far I have not been successful, I hope someone can help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
import numpy as np

ref = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

# get first row of each stretch
m1 = df['ciclo'].diff().ne(1)
# form groups
group = m1.cumsum()

# identify groups equal to ref
m2 = (df.groupby([group, 'equipo'])['ciclo']
        .transform(lambda s: np.array_equal(s, ref))
      )

# increment count
df['id_nuevo'] = (m1&m2).cumsum().where(m2)
```

Output:

```
         id  ciclo equipo  id_nuevo
0   1428171      3   Eq01       NaN
1   1427533      4   Eq01       NaN
2   1427950      5   Eq01       NaN
3   1427956      6   Eq01       NaN
4   1427957      1   Eq01       1.0
5   1427960      2   Eq01       1.0
6   1427913      3   Eq01       1.0
7   1430050      4   Eq01       1.0
8   1431974      5   Eq01       1.0
9   1431534      6   Eq01       1.0
10  1428030      1   Eq01       NaN
11  1428031      2   Eq01       NaN
12  1427930      3   Eq01       NaN
13  1427601      1   Eq01       2.0
14  1427578      2   Eq01       2.0
15  1427927      3   Eq01       2.0
16  1427532      4   Eq01       2.0
17  1427977      5   Eq01       2.0
18  1427980      6   Eq01       2.0
19  1433246      3   Eq01       NaN
20  1433251      4   Eq01       NaN
21  1427585      1   Eq01       3.0
22  1427974      2   Eq01       3.0
23  1427910      3   Eq01       3.0
24  1430905      4   Eq01       3.0
25  1431681      5   Eq01       3.0
26  1432176      6   Eq01       3.0
27  1433005      1   Eq01       NaN
28  1434616      2   Eq01       NaN
29  1433245      4   Eq01       NaN
```

Intermediates:

```
         id  ciclo equipo     m1  group     m2  m1&m2  (m1&m2).cumsum()  id_nuevo
0   1428171      3   Eq01   True      1  False  False                 0       NaN
1   1427533      4   Eq01  False      1  False  False                 0       NaN
2   1427950      5   Eq01  False      1  False  False                 0       NaN
3   1427956      6   Eq01  False      1  False  False                 0       NaN
4   1427957      1   Eq01   True      2   True   True                 1       1.0
5   1427960      2   Eq01  False      2   True  False                 1       1.0
6   1427913      3   Eq01  False      2   True  False                 1       1.0
7   1430050      4   Eq01  False      2   True  False                 1       1.0
8   1431974      5   Eq01  False      2   True  False                 1       1.0
9   1431534      6   Eq01  False      2   True  False                 1       1.0
10  1428030      1   Eq01   True      3  False  False                 1       NaN
11  1428031      2   Eq01  False      3  False  False                 1       NaN
12  1427930      3   Eq01  False      3  False  False                 1       NaN
13  1427601      1   Eq01   True      4   True   True                 2       2.0
14  1427578      2   Eq01  False      4   True  False                 2       2.0
15  1427927      3   Eq01  False      4   True  False                 2       2.0
16  1427532      4   Eq01  False      4   True  False                 2       2.0
17  1427977      5   Eq01  False      4   True  False                 2       2.0
18  1427980      6   Eq01  False      4   True  False                 2       2.0
19  1433246      3   Eq01   True      5  False  False                 2       NaN
20  1433251      4   Eq01  False      5  False  False                 2       NaN
21  1427585      1   Eq01   True      6   True   True                 3       3.0
22  1427974      2   Eq01  False      6   True  False                 3       3.0
23  1427910      3   Eq01  False      6   True  False                 3       3.0
24  1430905      4   Eq01  False      6   True  False                 3       3.0
25  1431681      5   Eq01  False      6   True  False                 3       3.0
26  1432176      6   Eq01  False      6   True  False                 3       3.0
27  1433005      1   Eq01   True      7  False  False                 3       NaN
28  1434616      2   Eq01  False      7  False  False                 3       NaN
29  1433245      4   Eq01   True      8  False  False                 3       NaN
```

Comment: *NB. the role of "equipo" is unclear, you might want to use `groupby.cumsum` if yuo want to restart the count per team